# the Use of Swagger

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-2.0

In Spring Boot, can Swagger 2 load different properties (cn or en) files according to different language environments (Chinese or English)? In these files, I define the Chinese and English descriptions of classes, methods, input parameters, etc. I want to generate different API documents based on different language environments

Also, does Swagger need to specify the properties path to load? I saved the file in /i18n buddle(Springboot default resource path)  and couldn't find it.

I have already used the form of @ propertySource to load the specified file, but it cannot be loaded according to different language environments, and the message of @ ApiResponses cannot be parsed

thank you!

I hope Swagger can display different API documents according to different language environments